# Error when importing package import org.apache.spark.Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

when importing package org.apache.spark.Row, I received error "object Row is not a member of package org.apache.spark". 
I created a maven project follow the tutorial. updated the POM.xml by adding below contents. did I miss any files?

```
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka_2.10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- mixed scala/java compile -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- for fatjar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-scala-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.15.2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute></execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Comment: Row is class of `org.apache.spark.sql` . You need to do `import org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Cross check the version of spark core and spark sql should be same.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

This should work.